# Unity Web Request Post

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I am trying to post request via `UnityWebRequest.Post` method but got this error

> "Curl error 1: Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed".

Below mentioned is my code:

```cs
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("username", userName);
form.AddField("password", password);

using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://193.16.117.212:48080/login", form))
{
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

    if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(webRequest.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete");
    }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is this server owned by you? The url "http://193.16.117.212:48080login" looks invalid, are you missing a `/` after the port?

Comment: http://193.16.117.212:48080/login that is the correct URL. Yes, the url is from the internal server.

Comment: The problem is on the server. Can you tell me what server are you using? Can you run `curl -v http://193.16.117.212:48080/login` to see what it will return?

Comment: @shingo it is returning this:

curl -vhttp://193.16.117.212:48080/login
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
 -d, --data <data>   HTTP POST data
 -f, --fail          Fail silently (no output at all) on HTTP errors
 -h, --help <category>  Get help for commands
 -i, --include       Include protocol response headers in the output
 -o, --output <file>  Write to file instead of stdout
 -O, --remote-name   Write output to a file named as the remote file
 -s, --silent        Silent mode
 -T, --upload-file <file>  Transfer local FILE to destination

Comment: @shingo answer continued:

 -u, --user <user:password>  Server user and password
 -A, --user-agent <name>  Send User-Agent <name> to server
 -v, --verbose       Make the operation more talkative
 -V, --version       Show version number and quit

This is not the full help, this menu is stripped into categories.
Use "--help category" to get an overview of all categories.
For all options use the manual or "--help all".

Comment: There is a space after `-v`

Comment: @shingo it returned this:

*   Trying 193.16.117.212:48080...
* Connected to 193.16.117.212 (193.16.117.212) port 48080 (#0)
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: 193.16.117.212:48080
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

Comment: According to the messages, the service at the address 193.16.117.212:48080 doesn't look like a HTTP service because it returns nothing for the request. Are you sure you have configured it? Can you access it with a browser?

Comment: @shingo it has been developed by one of my colleagues. He could configure it with the code mentioned below written in C#.

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
        HttpClient myHttpClient = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler())
        {
            DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20,
            DefaultVersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact
        };

Comment: myHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://193.16.117.212:48080");
        string requestUrl = "/login";
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", "kiaaa2" }, { "password", "kiaaa2" } };
        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent (parameters);
        Console.WriteLine($"GET {requestUrl}.");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, encodedContent);
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Response Body Length is: {responseBody.Length}");

Comment: @shingo The problem is I could not implement the same code inside unity as SocketsHttpHandler class is not recogniseable. Moreover, the server is only configured with using http2. I do not know if UnityWebRequest supports http2 or not.

Comment: It doesn't support http/2. You may try HttpClientHandler with HttpClient.

Comment: @shingo Can you please give an example, how?

Comment: @shingo Thanks. But with HTTPClientHandler how can I set the version to http2. Can you please reply with the syntax?

I am sorry I am not a very expert into it.

Comment: It seems like you don't have to specify the version. A default `new HttpClient();` will just work.

Comment: @shingo A default HttpClient has sync methods which seem to not work with unity. I have tried implementing them using Result property which makes the operation asynchronous, but it did not work.

Comment: What platform is your unity project running? Now I know is [http/2 is supported on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/), and you can also try this nuget package: [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/)

Comment: @shingo I am using Windows 10 Education Edition. Let me try the package you mentioned.